# What happens when we kill a long running query which in turn has executed another long running query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to kill a long running query by identifying the Session id of the query.

```
SELECT 
    r.session_id                 'Session ID',
    DB_NAME(r.database_id)       'Databse Name',
    st.TEXT                      'Batch Text',
    qp.query_plan                'XML Plan',
    r.start_time                 'Start Time',
    r.status                     'Query Status',
    r.total_elapsed_time/60/1000.0   'Total Elapsed Time'
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) AS qp
ORDER BY cpu_time DESC;

KILL {r.session_id}
```

What I understand is if parent query identified by r.session_id has started another query then the child will be terminated automatically since the parent session has been killed.

Are there any other considerations involved while doing this?

Comment: you are killing a select query. nothing would go wrong.

Comment: What is "parent query"? How can one "long running session" start smth else  if it did not finish what it's executing now?

Comment: @Steve Why do you think he is killing SELECT query?

Comment: @sepupic, I am trying to refer a nested stored procedure in which the main procedure is calling another SP inside it which in turn calls another SP and so on.